# wget performance for large downloads, and why does it take so long before it starts downloading?

Tags: ftp, wget, file-transfer

I'm going to be using wget to download a fairly large amount of data (~50-100 GB, a few thousand files) from a server. It's going to be fairly time-critical so I wanted to ask a few questions about performance.

1) When running wget, there seems to be a very long initial stage where there is no download happening, and then it suddenly starts. This stage seems to be noticeably longer than the actual download. What happens during the beginning of a wget process and is there a way to speed it up?

During this stage there is no network activity and wget doesn't seem to be very active on `top`. Could it have something to do with the `-erobots=off` option for wget?

2) The file structure I'm going to download is like so:

```
.../main_dir/
    000001/
        file1
        file2
        ...
    000002/
        ...
    ...
```

With `main_dir` containing in total about 50-100GB. However, if I try to recursively download `main_dir` with a command like this:

```
wget -q -nH --cut-dirs=6 -r --level=7 -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*' -erobots=off https:.../main_dir/
```

It doesn't work (it just hangs there). Is that because there's a file size limit to what a single wget command get pick up? Because the same command works if `main_dir` contains about ~10GB.

Also, are there alternatives or any special tricks one would use when trying to download 100GB from a server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for answers to this, here's what I learned since then. There is indeed a slow indexing step at the beginning, which can be avoided by using `lftp` and mirroring the site:

```
lftp -e "mirror path/to/dir/; quit" site.url
```

This is much faster, and also supports multiple stream downloading (see the documentation), which ended up reducing my download times from ~12-24 hours to ~1 hour for very large transfers.